# How do I get only part on the string out

Tags: powershell, virtualbox

we want to pause a VM in Oracle VirtualBox when it is being used on internal network and when we list the VMs then I get the below output but to pause the VM I need to have only the VM names out as people will create their own VMs so can't name them specifically. Problem is just that my powershell skills is not that great and when I try to use split or replace I run in to an error about the space ot the curvy brackets and what I want to end out with is just the VM name WIN10_VM1 but how to get that?

```
"WIN10_VM1" {bd9e16dc-1a1a-4340-aed2-af3b72f25c4f}
"win2019" {20fb95cb-2fb3-48f8-a69d-a1e00ca014b5}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to add the code that you've tried, then we can show you how to fix it.

Comment: Can you show us code you've attempted this with, can you show us your current output and also your expected output?

Comment: Where does that output come from?

Comment: I just run "VBoxManage.exe" list vms" from the VirtualBox folder but I need to only get the VM name out instead of also the SID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerShell exposes the entire .NET environment. So you can use the [Sytem.String.Substring()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.8) method.

```
& "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" | ForEach-Object { $_.Substring(0, $_.IndexOf("{")).Replace(" ", "") }
```

Comment: This is how I list them
PS C:\Temp> & "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" list vms
"WIN10_VM1" {bd9e16dc-1a1a-4340-aed2-af3b72f25c4f}
"win2019" {20fb95cb-2fb3-48f8-a69d-a1e00ca014b5}

Comment: Can you please try `PS C:\Temp> $vms = & "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe"; Get-Member -InputObject $vms` and tell me the "TypeName" from the top of the list?

Comment: TypeName: System.Object[]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Pim for pointing me in the right direction. Now I got the output of only the VM names with the below commands so now I can work on the next step of the script :)

```
$vms = & "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" list vms| ForEach-Object { $_.Substring(0, $_.IndexOf("{")) }
$test = $vms -replace '[\W]', ''
$test
```

Output:

**WIN10_VM1**
**win2019**

Comment: Considering my answer lead you to a solution. It is considered proper etiquette on the site to suggest an edit and accept my answer. Posting your own answer, which is a 98% derivative of mine is not considered appropriate.

Comment: Sorry Pim first time here and not trying to take credit of your work. I pushed a green check mark on your answer is that what you wanted me to do? Again thanks a lot for the help

Comment: It's no problem. I appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

To implement a regex solution, you can use `-replace` or `Select-String`.

---

**Using `Select-String`:**

```
($vms | Select-String -Pattern '(?<=^")[^"]+').Matches.Value
```

---

**Using `-replace` with Capture Groups:**

```
$vms -replace '^"([^"]+)".*','$1'
```

---

**Regex Explanation:**

- `(?<=^")`: Positive lookbehind assertion `(?<=)` that the first character on a line is `"`.
- `[^"]+`: Matches one or more (`+`) characters that are not `"`.
- `.*`: Matches all characters except newline.

The parentheses usage `([^"]+)` identifies the `[^"]+` match as a capture group. Since it is unnamed, it becomes capture group 1. When setting the replacement string with the `-replace` operator, you can access capture groups. `$1` represents capture group 1 and must either be surrounded by single quotes or backtick escaped if between double quotes. This is to avoid PowerShell performing interpolation on `$1`.